# Eagle tStop pad colliding with other pads

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers

[image: tStop colliding]

As you can see from the image, the tStop layer is colliding/wildly close with other tStop pad layer. Is that a cause of concern?

IC is Linear Technology battery management IC - LTC4155. Package is 28 pin QFN. The center big block is the ground pin(I drew that with a big SMD, is it OK?).
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4155fc.pdf

Answer (score 4):

tStop/bStop are simply where the solder mask should *not* be.  Collisions are not an issue since it just means that two regions without solder mask are touching.

More importantly is the size/spacing of the pads themselves.  As long as you followed the datasheet recommendations, you should be fine.

Comment: Datasheet recommendations, _and_ PCB warehouse requirements.